# Kali+Ubuntu+Parrot Security Armhf Image's on same multiboot SD card howto?

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, linux, operating-systems, security

Ive installed a bunch of Armhf linux distros to the PI 3 and with allot of success.  However i cannot find a good tutorial on installing them all on one SD Card. Im not talking about the preloaded OS's on berryboot or NOOBS.

All the tutorials ive read about installing multiple OS's or 3rd party linux OS's all refer to berryboot or NOOBS when the correct titles for those tutorials should be "Installing the preinstalled OS's that come on berryboot and NOOBS, using berryboot or NOOBS."

Specifically I want Parrot Security and Kali, METASPLOIT for my pentesting lab, plus a server flavor, dont mind either Debian or Ubuntu for  traning and testing security  LAMP Lab.   Plus being able to add windows Arm and or Android for a mobile programing and development Lab would be a plus too. I havent messed around with Raspian much, only enough to see that 99% of the security tools for kali/backtrack wont install on Raspian.

I understand allot of tutorials refer to using NOOBS and berryboot to install multiple OS's, but they come with multiple OS's and it would seem obvious you can install the ones that come with it, however others dont see it that way.

Im looking for guidence on the OS's for linux flavors that dont come on NOOBS and berryboot, however if theres some trick using these to load multiple OS not preinstalled with NOOBS or Berryboot please help me,

thankyou!

EDIT----EDIT----EDIT
OK got 2 OS's using that script, ParrotSec and Deb Jessie, I guess they use the same kernal Im not sure, but its giving me the option to pick and both load, I havent updated-upgraded either yet to see if they continue to work as they update them. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Have you considered a solution like the [WDLabs PiDrive][1]?  Granted it uses NOOBS but once a stack is in place you might be able to bitbang more OSes onto it.  They even support multiple boot options.

  [1]: http://%20http://wdlabs.wd.com/products/wd-pidrive-foundation-edition/#hdd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason tutorials mention berryboot or NOOBS are because AFAIK they are the only boot managers for the Pi. I wouldn't use either, because they create too many problems with updating.

You CAN install other OS into different partitions, and manually change the boot partition to load the appropriate OS. It wouldn't be hard to write a script to do this. The `/boot` partition should be the same for all OS, just change `root=/dev/mmcblk0p2` to point to other `ext4` partitions with the OS; each OS would need to have `/etc/fstab` customised to match the partition the OS is in. NOTE all OS should be using the same kernel.

Frankly it is easier to just use separate SD Cards.